# Unicode Normalization Form C in ASP.NET Core Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unicode, razor-pages

I am doing a [W3C validation](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) on an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor View but W3C gives me warning:

> Warning: The value of attribute alt on element img from namespace
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml is not in Unicode Normalization Form C.
>
> Warning: The value of attribute title on element img from namespace
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml is not in Unicode Normalization Form C.

My data is stored in a MSSQL database as `nvarchar` and everything else is set to UTF-8.

**Controller**

```
    using Dapper;
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public class FileViewModel
    {
        public int FileId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
    }

    private async Task<FileViewModel> LoadFileAsync(int id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Conn-string-here"))
        {
            const string sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Files WHERE FileId=@Id";

            var data = await conn.QueryAsync<FileViewModel>(sql, new { id }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return data.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    [Route("~/file/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> File(int id)
    {
        FileViewModel m = await LoadFileAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Return View(m);
    }
```

**Razor view**

```
@model FileViewModel

<img src="@Model.Source" alt="@Model.Title" title="@Model.Title" />
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="my description" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="my keywords" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- Auto generated from database: -->
<img src="https://example.org/img.png" alt="Fora&#x30A;r" title="Fora&#x30A;r" />

</body>
</html>
```

It seems W3C does not like the string `"Fora&#x30A;r"` but needs `"Forår"` instead.

How can I force ASP.NET Core Razor views to produce proper formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to represent the character `å`:

1. Using the Unicode codepoint U+00E5 ([latin small letter A with ring above](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00E5/index.htm)).
2. Using the combination of the two code points U+0061 ([latin small letter A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm)) and U+030A ([combining ring above](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/030A/index.htm)).

Visually, they cannot be distinguished. And it is not related to HTML, which can represent both versions - either directly (using UTF-8, UTF-16) *or* using an escaped version (like `&#x30A;`).

In your case, the second way to represent `å` is used.

In order to manage this ambiguity, Unicode has four [normalization forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/): *C*, *D*, *KC* and *KD*.

Unicode normalization is also supported by C#, more specifically by [String.Normalize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.normalize?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Normalize_System_Text_NormalizationForm_).

So in order get rid of the warning, normalize the *title*:

```
[Route("~/file/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> File(int id)
{
    FileViewModel m = await LoadFileAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    m.Title = m.Title.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
    return View(m);
}
```

In the long run, it's probably better to normalize all strings before storing them into a database. If the same text can be represented with different codepoint sequences, it will also cause troubles in database queries. And most database are unable to normalize strings.